# Creating, Reading from and Deleting Local Files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8

In Windows 8, (for Desktop Apps - Not Metro), how would you go about creating files, writing to them and reading from them?

---

The following link provides no information about this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447209(v=vs.85).aspx

I know how to do it in Metro apps, but where's the documentation?

Comment: I'd assume for desktop applications it would be exactly the same as normal?

Comment: So while Metro apps get all the awesome async and other benefits, Windows 8 desktop apps are the same as Windows 7? Sigh. I really hope a Touch-centric UI for Windows 8 was not the only reason for a new OS release

Comment: what are you missing/expecting in terms of creating/reading/writing files that wasn't already something you could do in Windows 7 via the .NET Framework?

Comment: I just wish they'd be more consistent. So far from what I can gather, in Metro-style apps, you handle IO one way (the new way - which is awesome, btw), and in Windows 8 WPF Desktop apps, you still handle that stuff the "old" way - even though it's a Windows 8 app, you're missing out on all the cool stuff you get with Metro apps.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you would have the full .NET framework at your disposal, the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class should help in that case.